# Finding a unique file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, hash, command-line

Is there a way I can find a unique/modified file?

I have two text files with hash and names eg:

file1.txt:

```
   c3f2b563b3cb091esada5b40fbfd5e60f526da3d *10.88.10/1.xml
   770aafff757f83e55c4cadaad7144e512299788d *10.88.10/config/2.csv
   38045a78f87addaddada4c3754bea76c72cbfe25 *10.88.10/3.txt
   asddd132dfdada1231431411ddsfadfgdkkgdada *10.88.10/4.js
```

file2.txt:

```
c3f2b563b3cb091esada5b40fbfd5e60f526da3d *10.88.12/1.xml
770aafff757f83e55c4cadaad7144e512299788d *10.88.12/config/2.csv
38045a78f87addaddada4c3754bea76c72cbfe25 *10.88.12/3.txt
asddd1222131231231sadsdaddsfadfgdkkgdada *10.88.12/4.js
dadadadawqeqweqwg32542362436532wqrewqr32 *10.88.12/5.py
```

As you can see some of the files in `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` are the same. `file2.txt` has a file added called `5.js` and an updated/modified file named `4.js`.

Is there any way I can output modified and added files in `file2.txt`?

Expected Output:

```
    10.88.12/4.js
    10.88.12/5.py
```

I tried the `diff` command but it shows all files are different because of file name  (10.88.10 to 10.88.12).

I tried `cut -d' ' f1` but after the `diff` command I couldn't find a way to output the file name.

Comment: Is there an extra whitespace before `*` in `dadadadawqeqweqwg32542362436532wqrewqr32  *10.88.12/5.py`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next}; { if (c[$1] == 0) print $2; }' File1.txt  File2.txt
*10.88.12/4.js
*10.88.12/5.py
```

Based on
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174599/using-diff-on-a-specific-column-in-a-file